# Upload and save image ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, save-image

Can i upload image and save it in my project directory?

input for upload images

```
<div class="tab">
          <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-3" class="tab-switch" />
              <div class="tab-content"> 
               <label><span>Images <span class="required">*</span></span><br></br>  
               <input id="file" type="file" multiple onChange={fileSelectedHandler} name="images" value={files} /></label>
              <input type="submit" onClick={handleClick} value="Add message"  class="submitButton"/>
          </div>
     </div>
```

`
I can upload images, but how can i save it in directory folder?
Thanks!

Comment: What are you using as a backend?

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann Spring Framework

Comment: its not about react and client side, you should change your question and keywords to java and spring.

Comment: @MohsenMahoski i want to save it using js, not java, because i want to store it in my react-project directory

Comment: you want to upload your image to backend and save it in the backend directory right?

Comment: @MohsenMahoski i want to upload and save image in the frontend directory

Comment: for saving any files from your clients you need a server, you cant do this with a react application ,You should prepare an endpoint for receiving and saving it , after that your server return a download link to your client and you can prepare a download link in client side , when user clicks on link file will be download.